# Angular 2 plain ES6 - how to declare ViewChild?

Tags: ionic-framework, angular, ionic2

I wonder if there is any way to use `@ViewChild(Class) variable` in plain ES6 (using babel-transform-decorators) in Angular 2?

I've seen that there are `providers`, `viewProviders` and `queries` properties in `@Component` declaration, but I had no luck in using them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the following:

```
@Component({
  queries: {
    variable: new ViewChildren(
                Class)
  }
})
(...)
```

This link could interest you (in the "Query Decorators" section):

- https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/ts-to-js.html

Comment: That's correct, I've tried this but I referenced ViewChildren from wrong package. Thanks